# creating dictionary from terminal. How to insert words into a txt file?

Tags: ruby, terminal

I am trying to take this output from this command:

```
cat /usr/share/dict/words
```

and put it into a text file. I eventually want to create a class method that takes a string of words like ("cat, dog", "xysafjkdfj") and sees which one of the words is not in the dictionary. How do I do this?

I did:

```
cat /usr/share/dict/words >> dictionary.txt
```

Is there another way?

Basically, I am trying to write a Ruby program that checks if certain words given to the class are included in this dictionary.

Comment: `/usr/share/dict/words` is already a text file. Please explain a bit more on what exactly you need.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might want to mention how you plan on using this because `grep` could do what you wanted e.g. `grep '^word$' /usr/shared/dict/words`

Nonetheless, all you want to do is slurp up all the text and split it on newlines (\n). Then you could just check to see if the array includes the word youre looking for.

so for a bare-bones example

```
dictionary = `cat /usr/share/dict/words`.split("\n").map(&:downcase)
dictionary.include? "foo"
# => true
dictionary.include? "akjsdfakjd"
# => false
```

a more ruby-ish example (not tested)

```
class Dictionary
  attr_reader :words

  def initialize(src = '/usr/share/dict/words')
    @words = File.read(src).split("\n").map(&:downcase)
  end

  # you could probably even delegate this
  def include?(word)
    words.include? word
  end
end

dict = Dictionary.new
dict.include? "foo"
# => true
```

Comment: What's the difference between putting ``cat /usr/share/dict/words`` in ticks and just cat /user/share/dict/words in irb?

Comment: the back-ticks allow you to execute shell commands and get the output from within ruby code. http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Kernel.html#method-i-60 . I'm only using it here as a quick and dirty way to get the words.